Can one force their way into their own house?
Bob owns a house in a stand-your-ground (i.e. no duty to retreat) US state. Or in a state where the duty to retreat has the exception of one's home.
One day he returns back after some (not very long) time away and finds that the house has been occupied by some rogue character Rob who threatens to open fire if Bob forces his way in.
Bob thinks "this is my house, so I can shoot the intruder". He forces his way in and manages to shoot Rob dead before he tries to shoot him.
Did Bob have the right to do so, or did he commit a crime?
Does it make any difference if Rob is no stranger but a co-owner of the house?
Does it make any difference if the property boundary matches the house walls i.e. Bob is not on his property when standing just outside the door?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

There are so many problems with this question for the details that it does not provide. The only rational approach in my opinion is to either close it for lack of focus or to answer it based only on the information that it provides, and assume no overt act that wasn’t mentioned. I’ll take the latter approach.
Bob is going to jail today for some form of homicide. If the case goes to trial, he will probably be convicted of some degree of murder, or possibly manslaughter.
No matter if a state features a Stand Your Ground law or a Castle Doctrine, that doesn’t give Bob license to start blasting away just because someone is in his house. It applies equally whether the person is a harmless old lady suffering from dementia who wandered in because she was confused, or whether it was Rob, who Bob believed is the same person who just told him that if he comes through that door, he’s going to kill him.
According to your narrative and what it left out --

Rob didn’t point a gun at Bob.
He didn’t move toward Bob.
Bob was able to see both of Rob’s hands and he wasn’t holding a weapon.
Rob didn’t make a furtive movement that Bob interpreted as going for a gun.
Bob doesn’t even know if he was the same person who talked to him through the door.

Bob failed the most basic test of the lawful use of deadly force in self-defense, namely, would a reasonable person, given exactly what Bob experienced, be put in fear of imminent death or serious bodily harm unless he used deadly force to protect himself? No, certainly not. He broke through the door and started shooting because of what he imagined would happen. Big bad Rob was all talk from behind a locked door, but he didn’t attempt to do anything to Bob. Bob’s going to jail.
Furthermore, every Stand Your Ground law that I’ve read in detail gives justification for the use of deadly force in lawful self defense without a duty to retreat only if you are not the initial aggressor. In the incident that you described, Bob was the only aggressor --  the only person who committed a violent act.
When the jury comes to the part where they decide what form of homicide Bob is guilty of, and if they are involved in sentencing, how long he’s going to be locked up, the prosecutor will ask them if they think he acted reasonably when he broke through the door. Was there some life and death reason that he absolutely had to get into his house right at that minute? Even though the guy on the other side of the door said he was going to kill him if he did? Is that the act of a reasonable person? The prosecutor will contend and the jury will agree that Bob could have called the police and waited for them around the corner instead of going in guns blazing. And I think the jury would agree.

Actually, he did not specify that he could see that Rob was harmless.

@Mary Right, agreed. Nor did he specify anything that Bob saw before he shot Rob. That's the point of taking the answer in this direction. It assumes no overt act or condition that could justify the use of force, because none was stated.

Did you see the line "manages to shoot Rob dead before he tries to shoot him"? How is it possible to not understand that Rob indeed held a gun, pointed it to Bob and was clearly intending to shoot (or, perhaps, even fired shots but missed)? This vigour in assuming facts in Rob's favour despite that the narrative clearly depicts him a determined offender is just astonishing.

@Greendrake Every aspect of the lawful use of deadly force turns on what the defender observes in the moments before that use, not what he imagines could happen. We have a voice making a threat. We have Bob thinking this is my house, so I can shoot the intruder and that is his intention as he breaks in. The narrative does not mention Bob actually seeing a gun pointed at him. The threat was in his mind. Rob was unarmed and bluffing. Bob committed murder. With the question so short on necessary details, this answer provides them for one possible outcome, a common practice on this Stack.

@MTA The narrative does not say that Bob's intention was to break in and just shoot Rob regardless of anything; it is your incorrect interpretation. IMO it should have been clear that Bob saw Rob actually try to shoot him before he pulled the trigger — precisely because I wrote "before he tries to shoot". I don't know why you understood the latter was merely in Bob's mind as opposed to what he actually saw. I narrated "before he tries to shoot" as a fact, not as Bob's thought, and a reasonable reader should have taken it as a fact.

@Greendrake The narrative does not say is exactly the point here. A question appears. It accumulates downvotes for its lack of essential detail. Numerous comments ask for clarification. The OP steadfastly lets the question stand and doesn't improve it. Votes to close accumulate because the question is unanswerable as it stands. Yet the question attracts considerable interest, so someone comes along and provides missing details of their own choosing to give one possible outcome in a legally grounded way. Nothing wrong with that. Other answers are possible, given different details.
